# FTP server performance

Tags: performance, ftp, stress-testing

I have build an FTP server which needs to be able to handle 2000Connexion/minute. Each client connect and upload some file to the server

I'm using pure-ftpd. Anyone knows what kind of server (I'm thinking in a VM on ESXi4.1) do i need and if it's possible for him to handle the load ?

May be i will use FTPS so the load may be more

---

**My Server :
16 Go DDR3
Intel Core i5-2400
4x3.1+ GHz
6 Mo L2 - QPI 5 GT/sec**

---

and last think, what about 2000Connexion/seconds
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to think of the bandwidth consumed on your server. Unlike HTTP connections  FTP connections can be very long when downloading a large file (even days if the files are very big).

But let's say that each session will take less than a minute to transfer the file. So you need 2000 concurrent connections.

Let's assume that your Co-location has 1 Gbps connection to the internet (it might have only 100mbps). 1000mbsp / 2000  = 0.5mbps or 512kbps transfer speed.  That is very slow and your end users will probably not be happy.

Also you have to think of the disk IO at this level. You will need a disk that can read/write random access files at 125MB/sec.

Before you even try to find a FTP server that can do this, make sure that your hardware and Internet connection can handle the traffic.